# Connect to remote Linux server and download images

Tags: shell, azure, docker, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I have a VM Linux server hosted in Azure and at each commit (VSTS) the latest images need to be running in the server.

I created a ssh file that cleanup the old images and containers, login to the Azure repositories, download the latest image and then run the images.

**EDIT**: In someway it works, but I get several errors saying:

```
2018-07-10T13:40:20.5189780Z ##[error]WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
2018-07-10T13:40:20.7698990Z Login Succeeded
2018-07-10T13:40:20.8902720Z ##[error]Unable to find image 'xxx/xxx:latest' locally
2018-07-10T13:40:22.3204967Z ##[error]latest: Pulling from webapp
2018-07-10T13:40:22.3265860Z ##[error]cc1a78bfd46b: Pulling fs layer
2018-07-10T13:40:22.3324371Z ##[error]ccd8cd166265: Pulling fs layer
2018-07-10T13:40:22.3426675Z ##[error]8dadded8f35b: Pulling fs layer
2018-07-10T13:40:22.3494260Z ##[error]4ac1a8781396: Pulling fs layer
2018-07-10T13:40:22.3557213Z ##[error]358b1e620f36: Pulling fs layer
2018-07-10T13:40:22.3618978Z ##[error]9ecafc783f75: Pulling fs layer
2018-07-10T13:40:22.3680191Z ##[error]bd4678161c75: Pulling fs layer
2018-07-10T13:40:22.3740329Z ##[error]4ac1a8781396: Waiting
2018-07-10T13:40:22.3800435Z ##[error]358b1e620f36: Waiting
2018-07-10T13:40:22.3866640Z ##[error]9ecafc783f75: Waiting
2018-07-10T13:40:22.3929010Z ##[error]bd4678161c75: Waiting
2018-07-10T13:40:22.9945500Z ##[error]8dadded8f35b: Verifying Checksum
2018-07-10T13:40:23.0005648Z ##[error]8dadded8f35b: Download complete
2018-07-10T13:40:25.0963066Z ##[error]ccd8cd166265: 
2018-07-10T13:40:25.1014550Z ##[error]Verifying Checksum
2018-07-10T13:40:25.1066534Z ##[error]ccd8cd166265: 
2018-07-10T13:40:25.1117790Z ##[error]Download complete
2018-07-10T13:40:26.7344417Z ##[error]4ac1a8781396: 
2018-07-10T13:40:26.7405020Z ##[error]Verifying Checksum
2018-07-10T13:40:26.7461298Z ##[error]4ac1a8781396: 
2018-07-10T13:40:26.7516892Z ##[error]Download complete
2018-07-10T13:40:28.0278005Z ##[error]cc1a78bfd46b: 
2018-07-10T13:40:28.0332847Z ##[error]Verifying Checksum
2018-07-10T13:40:28.0387928Z ##[error]cc1a78bfd46b: 
2018-07-10T13:40:28.0444564Z ##[error]Download complete
2018-07-10T13:40:28.4992403Z ##[error]9ecafc783f75: 
2018-07-10T13:40:28.5050705Z ##[error]Verifying Checksum
2018-07-10T13:40:28.5104450Z ##[error]9ecafc783f75: 
2018-07-10T13:40:28.5159300Z ##[error]Download complete
2018-07-10T13:40:30.3861425Z ##[error]bd4678161c75: 
2018-07-10T13:40:30.3913603Z ##[error]Verifying Checksum
2018-07-10T13:40:30.3969439Z ##[error]bd4678161c75: 
2018-07-10T13:40:30.4024295Z ##[error]Download complete
2018-07-10T13:40:33.4125795Z ##[error]358b1e620f36: 
2018-07-10T13:40:33.4178631Z ##[error]Verifying Checksum
2018-07-10T13:40:33.4237092Z ##[error]358b1e620f36: 
2018-07-10T13:40:33.4290332Z ##[error]Download complete
2018-07-10T13:40:54.0405962Z ##[error]cc1a78bfd46b: 
2018-07-10T13:40:54.0456335Z ##[error]Pull complete
2018-07-10T13:41:03.6392342Z ##[error]ccd8cd166265: 
2018-07-10T13:41:03.6445632Z ##[error]Pull complete
2018-07-10T13:41:04.5351618Z ##[error]8dadded8f35b: 
2018-07-10T13:41:04.5404186Z ##[error]Pull complete
2018-07-10T13:41:14.9043083Z ##[error]4ac1a8781396: 
2018-07-10T13:41:14.9094716Z ##[error]Pull complete
2018-07-10T13:41:37.4354624Z ##[error]358b1e620f36: 
2018-07-10T13:41:37.4408033Z ##[error]Pull complete
2018-07-10T13:41:37.8392568Z ##[error]9ecafc783f75: 
2018-07-10T13:41:37.8449868Z ##[error]Pull complete
2018-07-10T13:41:38.6568749Z ##[error]bd4678161c75: 
2018-07-10T13:41:38.6623600Z ##[error]Pull complete
2018-07-10T13:41:38.7540707Z ##[error]Digest: sha256:xxx
2018-07-10T13:41:38.8488559Z ##[error]Status: Downloaded newer image for xxx/xxx:latest 
2018-07-10T13:41:39.3152654Z ##[error]docker: Error response from daemon: network idm_bridge not found.
2018-07-10T13:41:39.3216281Z ##[error]Command failed with errors on remote machine.
2018-07-10T13:41:39.5011532Z ##[section]Finishing: Run shell script on remote machine
```

This is my ssh file:

```
# Cleanup
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)  # Stop all containers
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)    # Delete all containers
docker rmi $(docker images -q)  # Delete all images

# Download and run images
docker login xxx --username xxx --password xxx
docker run -d -p 5000:80 --network=xxx xxx/xxx
```

Comment: I don't see any errors, just a warning about --password. Unable to find image is normal because you just deleted the images with docker rmi. Pulling fs layer is normal output from docker pull when the image is not found locally.

Comment: @TeemuRisikko I updated my question

Comment: It looks like there's a pretty clear error in the output you've added; the mechanism seems to work fine.

Comment: You also might investigate automation tools like [Ansible](https://ansible.com/) that can do the "ssh to somewhere and do something" work for you.  A cluster manager like [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) can get heavyweight, but it will address the specific issue of "I built a new Docker image and now need my remote server to be running it".

Comment: @isidorouk You can check the network by `docker network ls` firstly. And you can also refer the similar issue here https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31226.

Comment: @isidorouk Has your problem been solved yet?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT nope

Comment: @What's the result if you execute the docker commands manually? Or what if you add `docker stack rm` in your ssh file?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT when I run the commands manually (not in a script file) I don't get any error.